# PHP offset warning on null

Tags: php, arrays

I should be getting an offset warning error in this code but it shows nothing. What am i missing ?

I have turned on error reporting etc.

```
<?php
$info = null;
$value = 'string';
if ($value == $info['firstname']){
 echo 'true';
}else{
 echo 'false';
}
?>
```

Comment: Interesting. This only gives an error in PHP7.4.0beta1 onward... https://3v4l.org/ZvNBA

Comment: I know this is not the answer to your problem, but surely just checking if the element exists is a common enough check that this problem (IMHO) should never matter in real code.

Comment: @NigelRen I agree. This is not a problem but sometime we just dont bother checking if every element exist or not depending on the situation. This errors  then help so much actually.

Comment: In answer to your now-deleted question, yes, you can make a website in PHP without using classes (object orientation, or OO). OO can be helpful in simplifying complex systems, but you don't have to use it.

Answer (score 3):

Prior to version 7.4 `Undefined index` throws for arrays only:

```
<?php
$info = [];
$value = 'string';
if ($value == $info['firstname']) {
 echo 'true';
} else {
 echo 'false';
}
?>
```